# Let $f :[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Prove that f is onto.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $f :[0,1] \rightarrow[0,1]$ be continuous with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Prove that f is onto.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $y \in [0,1]$ is not in the image of $f$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}([y,1])$ is closed. However, since $y$ is not in the image $f^{-1}([y,1]) = f^{-1}((y,1])$, which is open. But any interval is connected and the only sets which are both open and closed is empty set and $[0,1]$. $f^{-1}([y,1])$ cannot be the empty set since $f(1)=1$, and it cannot be the whole set either because $0 < y$. A contradiction, so $f$ must be onto.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: This is a nice proof.

Comment: Well, without reinventing the wheel, there's the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. It also follows from the facts that the image of a connected set is itself connected and the only connected sets in $\Bbb{R}$ are the intervals: The image f([0,1]) must be an interval in $[0,1]$ containing $0$ and $1$, hence $f([0,1])=[0,1]$.

Comment: That reasoning seems to involve quite some topology.

Answer (score 2):

This follows immediately from the intermediate value theorem, if you do not want to use topological notions such as connectedness. Namely, we can do the following:

Let $c \in [0,1]$ be given. If $c \in \{0,1\}$ we have already found a preimage. If not, then $f(0) = 0 < c < 1 = f(1)$. As $f$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem tells us there is an $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x) = c$. Hence $f$ is onto.